# Most durable bicycle frame: Titanium?

Tags: frames, steel, titanium

My Kuota carbon frame of 10 years is trashed. It was ridden for 100 000km in the most abhorrent weather conditions and never cleaned. It makes cracking sounds when under torsional loads, the steering tube jams and some screws are completely stuck despite not fully tightened.

I need a new bicycle frame, and I want it to last 50 years and I'm trying to figure out what material to use. Is Titanium just an overhyped, lighter steel frame for rich people, or is it truly indestructable and the be-all end-all of durability? Considering the price, am I better off replacing a steel frame every 10 years?

I gathered some prices from chinese retailers:

- Aluminum frame: 150$
- Steel frame: 300$
- Titanium frame: 1000$

EDIT:
Frames are cheap as they are manufactured in China. They are bulky and heavy and by no means low quality. Each frame weighs 2kg.

I don't care much about weight/performance. I need sturdy and bulky. (My high-end click pedals weighing 200g lasted 2 years. My Saint flat pedals for 60$ are still spinning like new after 8 years after driving through mud and snow and never cleaned) I will also make the shift from road bike to gravel bike.

Comment: I recommend stipulating in your question how willing you are over those 50 years to get the frame repaired and at what cost relative to replacement.

Comment: Get the frame repaired? I don't want to repair the frame, I want it to not break lol.

Comment: 100000km, wow!!

Comment: Are you trying to buy your way out of doing bike cleaning/maintenance ?

Comment: Unlikely a titanium or steel frame will outlast carbon, even more so if the bike maintenance is neglected. Are you sure its the frame? Sounds like a bit of maintenance on the headset and bottom bracket is all that's needed.  Stuck screws can probably be removed with right techniques.

Comment: Agree with mattnz. Unless your frame really has a crack or is making noises (e.g. because of loose bearing seats or the seatpost no longer fitting correctly) your problem is not the frame.

Comment: Another though - The modern bicycle is going the way of the penny farthing. Electric bikes  would have taken over everywhere except UCI races by now, except for their price. In a decade or two a modern bike today will be a quaint novelty from the past for a vast majority of riders. .  Also, you have a 10 year old frame, what are the chances you will be wanting to ride a new one in 50 years with modern advances in battery and motor tech and how old you will be.

Comment: A cheap frame in the mentioned price range will probably not last very long, independent of the material. Particularly titanium and carbon fiber are difficult to manufacture (bad welds, voids) and quality can't easily be judged. Considering that Ti bikes from reputable brands cost several times of what you mentioned, I wouldn't expect the cheap ones to last 50 years. So if it has to be cheap, steel is the only real option, but requires maintenance to prevent rust. Besides, if you spend that little on a frame, why not just buy a new one every 10 years...

Comment: Bike mechanic confirmed the frame is trashed. Steel from "cheap" frames is the same as from "expensive frames" and the welders are professionals. The only reason they are cheap is they are manufactured in china and they weigh 2kg.

Comment: @AzulShiva: have another mechanic from another shop give his opinion after cleaning the bike thoroughly. They should at least check the headset and BB bearings. Most like the other guy just wanted to sell an new bike.

Comment: @Criggie What's the point? Wiping muck off the frame wont make it last longer. It will be dirty again in 1 week. I replace all sprockets and the chain every spring without ever cleaning them and it doesnt cost me 100$. Friends of mine spend fortunes on their bicycles and they only ride it in sunny weather.

Comment: @Carel I actually did that. My mechanic is trusted, I know him for 10 years. He knows I will cheap out and by chinese anyway.

Comment: Remember all, comments are for clarifying and improving the question.  Answers go in Answers VVV down there.

Comment: If you believe steel from cheap frames is the same as steel used in expensive frames, we cannot answer the question as you are starting from a flawed premise. There is a very big difference in quality of steel used in bicycle frames at different price points.

Comment: @mattnz The steel used in the 200$ steel frame I am looking at is "4130 CR-MO Steel". By the way 1000$ kitchen knives are made of a chunk of steel worth less than 10$. Steel isn't expensive. Unless they are building the frames from recycled garbage, there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: " They are bulky and heavy and by no means low quality" Although it is true that too light frame may be light just for the sake of, sacrificing quality/durability, the opposite is not true. Heavy and bad quality? absolutely possible :D !
Cheap steel and good steel bikes are built with tubes of the same "4130 CR-MO Steel", but the way stress is distributed in the material depends on the details, such as badly executed welding, or poor geometries, or steel tubes thickness.  If poorly executed, these details may lead to increased stresses and to premature failing, all steel things equal.

Comment: This is a flawed premise for reasons in addition to what @mattnz said. 1. In 50 years, your body will not want to be on the same bike. 2. In 50 years, bike parts will probably have changed dramatically, and you may have trouble getting parts that fit. Unless you want this bike to be primarily an art project or philosophical statement, a 50-year stipulation is impractical.

Comment: @AdamRice In 50 years the bike will be passed down upon my grandchildren. And if parts have changed dramatically, you can drill new holes into steel to accomodate them. With carbon, that's impossible.

Comment: @EarlGrey Good points. However I doubt the issues will be as disastrous. Im expecting minimal quality differences, and large weight/performance differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From personal experience riding mostly steel and titanium (Ti) for decades, as well as general engineering understanding, I'd say ***probably* yes, Ti is the best** (in the same quality class, of course) if you're indeed "trying to buy your way out of doing bike cleaning/maintenance".

That said, this relates to the frame itself, while most maintenance is done on other parts. On a Ti frame, you will likely replace *everything* several times before the frame dies of neglect.

Even if, for the purposes of this answer, we ignore "repairability", a typical Ti frame will win over carbon in one important aspect in terms of longevity: it tends to use **standard ISO components** (headset, bottom brackets etc.) This will facilitate replacement later, in 10-30+ years time. Modern carbon frames tend to use a lot of custom components.

Even after 100K+ of lack of cleaning a Ti frame will be fine (mine is less K but 20+ years), provided it was designed and assembled well. But over that time, you will likely have some crashes and have some dents on it. That's about the worst that can happen (save for a wrecking damage).

(By the way, a Ti frame designed for longevity will not be the lightest: it will be about the same weight as good modern Al or even steel ones, i.e. in the vicinity of 1.2-1.3 kg. Avoid the lightest Ti frames, lest they will be too floppy (even if strong enough) and dented easily).

So, Ti frame might be the best choice if:

- You don't want to clean the frame and maintain its paint, and
- You prefer to [keep the same bike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus) and gradually replace its components as they wear, rather than buying a new bike every 10 years or so (even if the latter might be more cost-efficient in absolute terms).

Comment: I disagree on the difference between parts compatibility between Ti and Carbon (or steel of aluminum).  If the the rate of design obsolesce we see in MTB carries over to road, parts will be next impossible to get in a decade for any frame.

Comment: @mattnz, road components standards have 40+ years history. Standard components are so common they will probably always be available. It is true that manufacturers try to push users to their proprietary 'standards' (a sorry practice of many industries, esp. in the last decade or two), but if one cares about "50 years" of longevity, he will need to restrict himself only to the common standard (ISO) components, at the cost of fancy stuff like non-round seatposts. Ti (and steel) frames _tend_ to be more standards-based (which is somewhat fair as the standards were designed around classic frames).

Comment: It's more of a Ti vs Steel debate. Im done with carbon. The Ti & Steel frames from china come in at 2kg. I heard Ti frames are more prone to cracking and Steel frames are more prone to rusting. Confused as to how bad the problem is and how they compare against each other.

Comment: To all practical purposes, steel does not rust beyond cosmetic blemishes, at least high quality steel. If a bike is neglected enough for the frame to rust structurally, the components (worth many times more than the frame) deteriorate to unusable well before hand.

Comment: @AzulShiva, 2 kg is rather heavy even for a steel [road] frame. Perhaps it's with a fork? I haven't heard of Ti frames cracking more. On the one hand, Ti is more pliable and the walls will be thicker, which should cause it cracking _less_; but on the other hand, it's harder to weld Ti properly, and demands to quality are higher. Also, as I hinted, Ti is such a wonderful material it can easily be abused by making the frame _too_ light (yet still formally strong enough); but its other properties will suffer.

Comment: @mattnz, kind of true, but not necessarily for a good bike. Partially because other components are bound to be replaced more often. Chain will rust first, but it gets replaced most often (of other things) anyway. Most other components will be aluminium; what rusts are bolts and springs and such, which is also largely cosmetic. But even cosmetically, it matters. A 30 yo Ti frame will look just like new without much care (provided it is *un*painted, which is usually the case).

Comment: @AzulShiva Steel frame rusting is predominantly a function of paint job quality. If that's a high-quality powder coating, you should have no trouble with rust.

Answer (score 3):

With a well made frame, titanium is likely the most durable material.  Aluminum does fatigue while steel rusts.  Ti is about as strong as steel.  Personally my ti road bike is in its 20th year.

However titanium is only as good as its welds.  If it is not well made, you may have a failure on a weld point.